# Уровни изолированности транкзакций(ACID)

Tags: sql

Хочу подробно разобраться в уровнях изолированности транкзакций.
Пока что у меня получилось разобраться только в Read uncommitted и read committed.

Пример:
Есть массив например
1 2 3 4 5
Есть две параллельные транкзакций
Одна скажем делает +1
Вторая умножает на 2

Массив может получится
4 5 8 9 12

При read uncommitted транкзакции будут выполняться кто быстрее и получится не предсказуемое поведение, не то что нам нужно

Read committed фиксирует изменения и только после этого другая транкзакция видит эти изменения и вносит свои, она не видит записей которые не помечены committed.

Массив будет
4 6 8 10 12

А теперь прошу вас объясните пожалуйста как работает repeatable read?

И насчет serializible, я понимаю что он делает lock записи и прочее, работает медленнее, но как происходит фантомное чтение? Можно пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, мне очень помогла эта статья:
http://aboutmysqldb.blogspot.com/2013/?view=sidebar&_escaped_fragment_&m=1

Неповторяющиеся чтения - это проблема которая возникает у двух параллельных транкзакций.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на рисунке транкзакция 2 читает данные в один промежуток времени и во второй, но между этими 2 интервалами происходит update транкзакции 1 и когда транкзакция 2 повторно прочитает данные они будут неповторяющимися.

Фантомное чтение - это проблема где есть 2 параллельные транкзакции и у одной из них из ниоткуда появляется новые данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и в случае выше, транкзакция 2 делает insert в табличку и транкзакция 1 видит эту табличку и может внести изменения которые она применяла к другим записям во время своего выполнения.